# Google glog rolling files

Tags: c++, logging, glog

I'm want to use [google-glog](https://github.com/google/glog) (logging library) in my C++\Linux project.
And one of the most important feature for me, it's rolling files.
I.e. when log file size become more than fixed threshold, creates new log file and old was removed. Same for time limit (daily, hourly etc).

Maybe I missed something, but I can't find such functionality in this very good library.
Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: The documentation directs you to look in logging.cc

Answer (score 10):

For logfile size(Integer):

`GLOG_max_log_size`(Environmental variable) OR `--max_log_size=size`(if gflags is installed) OR `fLI::FLAGS_max_log_size=size`(in C++ code)

For logdir(Strings):

`GLOG_log_dir`(Environmental variable) OR `--log_dir=dir`(if gflags is installed) OR `fLS::FLAGS_log_dir=logdir`(in C++ code)

For logging to stderr(Boolean):

`GLOG_logtostderr`(Environmental variable) OR `--logtostderr=1`(if gflags is installed) OR `fLB::logtostderr=true`(in C++ code)

Likewise you can use following also:

- alsologtostderr, colorlogtostderr, log_prefix, stop_logging_if_full_disk from namespace `fLB` (all are Boolean)
- minloglevel, logbuflevel, logbufsecs, logemaillevel
  from namespace `fLI` (all are Integers)
- alsologtoemail, logmailer, log_link, log_backtrace_at from namespace `fLS` (all are Strings)

But above all do have a look on to glog_srource/src/logging.cc for more information as quamrana said.